# VBA code not copying range of data to other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple VBA script that copies data from one workbook to another, but it fails on copying this data to the other workbook. However it works when copying it from the same workbook to another column.

I get a runtime error 1004;

```
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

I have looked at various samples such as [this](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-ranges/#Selecting-a-Cell-Range-in-Excel-using-VBA) and [this](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-another-workbook/) and I cannot see why this error occurs, especially as I am allowed to copy it into the same workbook.

Below is my function you are able to where my commented line in the if statement I have changed it for the different workbook;

```
Sub Autofill()

    Dim message As String
    Dim data_exists As String
    Dim data_filename As String
    Dim data_wb_csv As Workbook
    Dim data_excel_workbook As Workbook
    Dim compt_wb As Workbook

    'get data file and convert to xlsx
    data_exists = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx")
    If data_exists <> "" Then
        Kill (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx")
    End If
    data_filename = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cover").Range("E10").Value
    data_wb_csv = Workbooks.Open(data_filename)
    data_wb_csv.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    'data_wb_csv.Close savechanges:=False
    'data_excel_workbook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx")

    'read in compt template
    compt_wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template\CoMPT_Convert_Template.xlsx")

    If data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "SiteName" Then
        If data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A3").Value = "" Then
            data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").Copy Destination:=compt_wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A3")
        Else
            data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=compt_wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A4") 'data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B3")
        End If
        message = "yes"
    Else
        message = "No"
    End If

    Msg.Box (message)

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: `data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=compt_wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A4") 'data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B3")` this one, here you can see the commented out code to copy in the same wb, this part worked

Comment: A few notes: 1. You should declare all variables, e.g. `data_exists`, `compt_wb` etc. etc. 2. `If Not data_exists = ""` is the same as `If data_exists <> ""`; makes it easier to read. 3. You don't need to close `data_wb` just to reopen it as `data_excel_workbook`. By using `.SaveAs` you have already created a copy of the workbook. 4. You don't need the `:` after `Else`. `:` allows you to continue writing in the same line, which you don't.

Comment: This is unqualified `Range("A2").End(xlDown)` - a very common problem.

Comment: @M.Schalk whoops, didn't realise the `:` I am coming from a python background, this is natural for me!

Comment: @SJR how comes it is unqualified? When I used it with the copy to the same workbook it worked. The explanation I looked at [here](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-ranges/#Selecting-a-Cell-Range-in-Excel-using-VBA) explained this to me. I am getting a bit lost now

Comment: Because it doesn't have a workbook or worksheet reference. Hence active file and sheet will be assumed and in that case the code will work. Otherwise it will error. There are countless examples of this at SO.

Comment: @M.Schalk I delcared the variables like you said, but now it is throwing errors saying that it has not been declared. I have amended code above

Comment: Oh sorry @M.Schalk ignore me, I removed the "Set"

Comment: @SJR I get you now, but not sure why it worked for the same wb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ranges aren't completely qualified, try this line:

```
data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2", data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=compt_wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A4")
```

Here is the complete code with some necessary corrections (specifically references to the correct workbook):

```
Sub Autofill()

Dim message As String, data_exists As String, data_filename As String
Dim data_wb_csv As Workbook, data_excel_workbook As Workbook, compt_wb As Workbook

'get data file and convert to xlsx
data_exists = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx")
'It's not necessary to use a seperate variable here but it doesn't hurt either
If data_exists <> "" Then Kill (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx")

data_filename = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cover").Range("E10").Value
'Variable also not necessary
data_wb_csv = Workbooks.Open(data_filename)
data_wb_csv.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Input\data.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'read in compt template
compt_wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template\CoMPT_Convert_Template.xlsx")

If data_wb_csv.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "SiteName" Then
    If data_wb_csv.Worksheets(1).Range("A3").Value = "" Then
        data_wb_csv.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").Copy compt_wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A3")
    Else
        data_wb_csv.Worksheets(1).Range("A2", data_wb_csv.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy compt_wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A4") 'data_excel_workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B3")
    End If
    message = "Yes"
Else
    message = "No"
End If

Msg.Box (message)

End Sub
```